# Properties reset everytime someone new connects in my Twisted socket [python]

Tags: python, sockets, twisted

I am trying to set it so that the property "Instance" is autoincrementing. I have been searching but I am also new to socket programming so I may have been asking the wrong questions. The end goal is to create a chatroom that can identify who is in which group. All of the tutorials online I have been able to find only show a very simple socket connection chatroom without elaborating on how the server should discern between different groups. 
I think the only thing I need to accomplish this is to get that variable to be autoincrementing instead of resetting every time a new user joins

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import json
class IphoneChat(Protocol):
     memberList={}
    Instance = 1
    def connectionMade(self):
        print "a client connected"
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print self.Instance
        self.Instance+=1
        self.factory.clients[-1].message("Connection Success")
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)
    def dataReceived(self, data):

        json_decoded = json.loads(data)
        Type=json_decoded[0]["type"]
        groupID=json_decoded[0]["groupID"]
        member=json_decoded[0]["member"]
        print Type
        if Type=="node":
            print "Node recc"
        elif Type=="create":
            print "group created"
            self.memberList[groupID]=[]
        elif Type=="con":
            print "Connection"
            self.memberList[groupID].append(member)
        elif Type=="dis":
            print "Disconnect"
            self.memberList[grouID].remove(member)
        elif Type=="poll":
            print "Poll"
        elif Type=="comment":
            print "Comment"
        else :
            print "unrecognized type"

        a = data.split(':')
        print a
        if len(a) > 1 :
            command = a[0]
            content = a[1]
            msg = ""
            if command == 'iam' :
                self.name = content
                msg = self.name + "has joined"
            elif command == "msg" :
                msg = self.name + ": " + content
                print msg
            for c in self.factory.clients:
                c.message(msg)
    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message +"\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the += increments the value on the *instance* rather than on the class itself (meaning that after you use `+=`, the instance now has a count of 2, but the class-level variable has the original count). To fix the issue, you just need to increment the value on the *type* (i.e., the class level dictionary) vs. the instance. Here's a minimal example of what's going on that should make things clearer.

```
class CountingClass(object):
    count = 1


>>> obj = CountingClass()
>>> obj.count += 1
>>> obj.count
2
>>> CountingClass.count
1
>>> CountingClass.count += 1
>>> CountingClass.count
2
>>> type(obj).count += 1
>>> CountingClass.count
3
```

You should use `type(obj)` if you want subclasses to have different counts (because they'll each have their own `__dict__` of data), otherwise you should use the actual class name explicitly.

Comment: I still have a little to figure out, but I gave you best answer for showing me where I went wrong conceptually, I think I can figure it out from here, thanks a bunch!